# C++ #ID <0 >100 == Invalid need hints/advice

Tags: c++

**Assignment: You also need to check if the grade user entered id in between 0 and 100. If not, print an error message and exit.** Not sure what he exactly means by that cause the user can exit it by himself or he means abort();?

So I was wondering if it's possible to do it with it posting only "Sorry but the number you entered is invalid, please enter any number between 1 - 100"

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
int grade;
cout << "What is your grade? ";
cin >> grade;

    if(grade>100){
        cout << "Sorry but the number you entered is invalid, please enter any number between 1 - 100";
    }
    else if(grade>=90){
        cout << "You have an A in the class" << endl;
    }
    if(grade<90){
        cout << "You have an B in the class" << endl;
    }
    else if(grade>=80){

    }
    if(grade<80){
        cout << "You have an C in the class" << endl;
    }
    else if(grade>=70){

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Answer (score 0):

Combine comparison expressions:

```
if ((grade < 0) || (grade > 100))
{
  // Invalid grade
}
else
{
  // Process grade
}
```

Comment: thanks for the hint/advice but I was too cocky(in class) so I wouldn't really utilize your hint to the fullest.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
if(grade>100){
    cout << "Invalid" << endl;
}
else if(grade>=90){
    cout << "You have an A in the class" << endl; 
}
```

Your problem is that you just have a load of if statements, any number of which can possibly match.  You need to have an else statement for each one after the first one to ensure it only matches one.

Is >100 the *only* failure point though?  What if <0?  or a letter?

Using return 0;

```
if(grade>100){
    cout << "Invalid" << endl;
    return 0;
}
if(grade>=90){
    cout << "You have an A in the class" << endl; 
    return 0;
}
```

If-Else-If is always preferable as far as I am concerned.

## Edit

```
if (grade > 100 || grade < 0)
{
    // error
}
else if (grade > 90)
{
}
else if (grade > 80)
{
}
else if (grade > 70)
{
}
else
{
     // failed
}
```

If you imagine it as a sequential chain of events.  If the first one doesn't match it checks the next and then the next and so on until the default of failure.  Once it finds a match then none of the subsequent else statements will be processed and the application will exit.  If you take the example of 75.  It will fail > 90 and > 80 and then pass > 70 at which point it will end.

Comment: oh ok this seems pretty easy now since with else only it isn't that logical.

Comment: It's pretty standard programming practice TBH - start with the highest possible success (or in your case a failure condition) and work your way down. Once one fails then check the next.  You could do it without the else by using return 0; after each statement.

Comment: would you mind giving an example of using return 0; instead of else

Comment: can you check my post again I used the else if but when I type in 75 it shows You got B AND C

Comment: If you are using else you need to have it in EVERY statement not just in a few places like you have there.

Comment: hmm I don't quite understand. I got 3 if's so I have 3 else if's am I not understanding something here?

Comment: Cool everything works now, I think I got a bit too cocky in class since I got A in java and Alice in the previous semester. I was daydreaming instead of paying 100% of my attention since I thought I was a coding god at the current level. The way I was approaching the problem was embarrassing.